# Tokenizing or Splitting String

Tags: java, android, split, stringtokenizer

I am having trouble tokenizing or splitting string on the basis of some delimeter. There are two type of Strings that I need to tokenize. Following is the pattern:

```
   a/b/c/d
```

and

```
   a/b//d
```

I am confused how to get both parsed by one function. As I cannot judge before parsing that which string is about to be parsed. As the data is dynamic. and I get `NoSuchElmenet Exception` when searching for next token if there is not any. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want us to tell you how to use a `for` loop? Please show some code, so we can understand, what you are asking for.

Comment: `string s = "a/b/c/d"; while(s != atMordor) { goto Mordor; } throw ring;`

Comment: Sorry, I thought you said *tolkienizing*...

Comment: If you are using `StringTokenizer` you can use `hasMoreTokens()`

Comment: "a/b/c/d".split("/");

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to get the tokens `{a, b, c, d}` or `{a, b, d}`, so, it's very easy using StringTokenizer class.

Look at this example:

```
String exampleA = "a/b/c/d";
StringTokenizer tokens=new StringTokenizer(exampleA , "/");
while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
    System.out.println(tokens.nextToken());
}
```

You'll get:

```
{a, b, c, d}
```

And, for the second example:

```
String exampleB = "a/b//d";
StringTokenizer tokens=new StringTokenizer(exampleB, "/");
while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
    System.out.println(tokens.nextToken());
}
```

You'll get:

```
{a, b, d}
```

I hope this is useful for you.

Cheers!

Comment: Please note, that `StringTokenizer` [should not be used anymore](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

Comment: You can use the "split()" method, instead. It's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to separate the two patterns or determine which one is which, try with the java Pattern class. Below, a quick solution

```
String testString = "a/b/c//d";
String checkfor = ".*//.*";
boolean matches = Pattern.matches(checkfor, testString);
```

The Pattern.matches() will search for the occurrence of two "/" followed by each other and return respectively (e.g "//" and not "/... /").

Good luck